# Peripheral working but not detected as new on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, headphone-jack

I'm using Windows 10, and when I plug in headphones, the sounds indeed goes into the headphones, but the mic stop working. I'm pretty confident the headphone is recognized as both input and output, but I don't have access to any usual option to separate it.
I realised that in my manager, if I look at the output peripheral, not matter if I plug the headphones or not, the output peripheral stay on "Speaker Realtek(R) Audio" (even if the sounds goes into headphones when plugged in) and the input peripheral stays on "Microphone Realtek(R) Audio".

How is that possible?

Comment: Please add screenshots.

Comment: `the output peripheral stay on "Speaker Realtek(R) Audio"` ... of course it does.  When you plug in (non-USB) headphones, your output device doesn't change.  You are simply changing the output speaker, not the audio device itself.  Are you sure that plug that you are plugging into supports both audio and microphone at the same time or do you have a separate jack for the microphone input?  Some machines need a splitter, some don't.